# Designating a pin header and a GPIO

Tags: python, embedded-systems, specifications, iot

I have an Acconeer [XB112 breakout board](https://www.acconeer.com/products) and an [XM112 radar module](https://www.acconeer.com/post/2019/02/13/xm112-radar-sensor-module).  It all works just fine per the Acconeer documentation and tutorials.

Now I want to modify some of the code to output to a GPIO. My problem is that there are six different header options: two micro USB (J1 & J2), two 2x5 headers (J5 & J6), a 2x30 board-to-board connector (J4; where the XB and the XM mate), and a 2x20 header (J3) that is only solder pads.

I need to use pin 5 on header J6.  How does one determine the name of the specific header and how would that be written in python?

Comment: I'm ok with the -1, but why?  How can I make this a better question?

Comment: not my vote, but see [Why are implementation and debugging questions off-topic on Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7864/31260)

Comment: Oh, ok.  Makes sense.  I'll go elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consult the documentation of the boards you are using.

The software can access GPIO pins of the microprocessor, but that processor can be mounted on a gazillion different board layouts and there is no way to tell the software what the board layout looks like.

As a result, you need to look in the documentation of your board which GPIO pin of the processor is connected to pin 5 of header J6 (if it is a GPIO pin at all. Not all processor pins are usable as GPIO pins, even if they are connected to a header).